# Deploying an Angular app with Azure Pipeline, Failed

Tags: angular, azure, azure-pipelines

I've built an Angular app that runs fine from localhost. I uploaded it to a GitHub repository and I am trying to connect it to an Azure Pipeline. But it always fails on NPM Install and Build. I am new to using Azure Pipelines and think that I may be running something incorrectly. Below is the yaml that was generated for me.

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: Are you getting an error on the steps that fail?

Comment: what is the errpr

Answer (score 0):

> Deploying an Angular app with Azure Pipeline, Failed

Since it works fine on your local, so the error should comes from the pipeline settings.

Please check if the following points that may cause errors are helpful to you:

First, when you create a pipeline, you need select the Github as the source location:

[image]

Second, we need **specify the working folder when we build the Angular app**, the working folder should be the relative path to the `.yml`.

So, I need specify the working foler when I build the Angular app by `pushd /path/to/dir`:

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    pushd AngularDemo/AngularDemo/ClientApp
    ng build --prod
    popd
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

As test, I could build the Angular app successfully with Azure devops pipeline.

If above not help you, please share your build error log and file directory structure on github.

Hope this helps.